# Android reset activity component state on navigation back

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, android-intent, navigation

I have 2 activities in my application.
In **activity1**, I set some configuration and I modify the state of some component (ex: set button state *disabled*). And I navigate to **activity2**.

In **activity2** I do some stuff and at end, I finish this activity and come back to **activity1**.

But In **activity1**, my components state are the same when I leave this activity.

How to reset the components state with valuesdeclared in **XML file** (*layout*) ?

Answer (score 3):

You have three callbacks in this instance available to you to manage the state of the Activity.

Since you are returning to the Activity, `onRestart()` will be called, and this callback is specific to this instance (it is not called the first the time Activity is created and displayed).

The other callbacks you will receive are `onStart()` and `onResume()`, which are also called any time that Activity comes to the foreground (include the first time).  More on the Activity lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

You may reset the state of your UI in any one of these places that best suits your application.  There is no direct "reset" method you can call on your views to set them back to the XML defined stage, though.  You will need to manually call the methods to set the view flags back to the state you require.

HTH

Comment: I am actually using this method (`onRestart`). But it's tedious to set manually each component...

Answer (score 3):

When you return to the previous activity as the result of calling finish() the onActivityResult method is called.
You can repopulate your view to the desired state within this method.

For example:

```
    ...
        Intent result_intent = new Intent();
        setResult( Activity.RESULT_OK, result_intent );
        finish();
    }
```

```
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
    {
        setContentView( R.layout.my_activity );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**there is no flag or attribute which can be set only in the xml files** to achieve what you want, but the good news are that what you describe can be done in a lot of ways:

**one way** is to do this **two** operations:

set your "activity1" attributes on the manifest.xml with property:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

this flag will remove the activity from stack when you navigate away from it.

then, override the **onBackPressed()** method of "activity2":

instead of:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

write:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

this will cause new instance of activity1 to be launched when user press back from activity2.

**second option**, is to follow **Devunwired** advice, and just implement on your "activity1" the **onResume()** method, which been called when the activity brought back to forground:

instead of:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

write:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

this implemetation would cause to "activity1" to "restart" by clausing and re-openning itself when it return to be forground

if you want to know what is the right thing to do from my point of view:  probably the reason you want to restart the activity is that you want to refresh some values and views state.  what you need to do is not to restart the activity, but to run on the onResume() method the code that "refreshes" the data and the appropriate views, and that's it.

Comment: *onBackPressed()* -> Since: API Level 5... I would like to be compatible from API Level 3.

Comment: @Aure77: supporting API 3  is so old...   I think that the company that forced you supporting API 3  made a mistake.  96% of android users using API 8 and above.  the API changed dramatically since API 3, and it's sad you can't use more modern and stable API

Comment: I agree with you, but some device with Android 1.6 are still in sale (ex: Low cost Tablet)